# Is this jQuery function possible with prototype?

Tags: magento, prototypejs, jquery

I'm working with Magento, and I'm fed up with its built-in prototype #%@$!!
I have the "[Pre-Select Colors Plus Swatches](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pre-select-colors-plus-swatches.html)" extension, and I'm also pissed with that, because it didn't do its job on pre-selecting products color atribute when the page loads.
I'v also spent a few hours trying to get jQuery noConflict() to work, but it crashes exactly the extension aforementioned. 
So I ended up with that jQuery code working, and need to translate it to Prototype, what seems impossible! This function simulates a click on the first available color option, and I call it after the page loads. Is it possible with prototype? How ???

```
$j("div.atributoProduto.Cor img.swatch:not('.disabledSwatch'):first").parent().click();
```

Also, if you can come up with a miracle code to make jQuery and prototype coexist, it would be nice. But I'v done some research and tried many ways to do it...

Comment: Have you tried `noConflict()` and just using `$` instead of `$j`?

Comment: Given that the select box is itself populated by javascript from JSON data, you may need to wait until *that* is done before trying to select something.

Comment: As mentioned in the question: "I'v also spent a few hours trying to get jQuery noConflict() to work, but it crashes exactly the extension aforementioned.". I cant use $, because Magento defaults to prototype wich uses the $, I tried using jQuery with "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();" with no success.

Comment: @benmarks The select box is populated by PHP, to be more precise, it is populated by `Mage::helper('colorselectorplus')->getSwatchHtml($_productAttribute->getAttributeCode(), $attributeId, $_product);`. And even if that was the problem, I could easily run the function after all that loading process, I need to translate that function to prototype or make jquery work without crashing other features.

Comment: @Lennon this is non-standard. Sounds like you need to get the vendor to support their extension.

Comment: @benmarks You hit a point again, but usually it take weeks or a couple of months to be resolved by the vendor, and I want to satisfy my client's interest even if as a client I`m not satisfied. Thanx anyway!

Comment: The ordering of your Javascript files matter in my experience. I've always put jquery to be loaded before any of the default JS libraries. Have you tried that yet at all?

Comment: @AshSmith No I didn't, many sources on internet says to include jquery after all, but It surely makes more sense using it first. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to load jQuery before any of the prototype code and then call noConflict on it. Maybe don't use `$j` as a replacement variable but use `jQuery` instead or something else non-short with a very low chance for collision.

```
//Load jQuery
<script>
  var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
//Load other Javascripts including Prototype
```

Prototype and jQuery should be able to coexist quite perfectly and if you load jQuery as the first one it will be cleared out of the global Namespace even before Prototype kicks in. This way there is no way it can conflict.

You don't need a short name for jQuery and it doesn't need to include a `$`

```
jQuery("div.atributoProduto.Cor img.swatch:not('.disabledSwatch'):first").parent().click();
```

Loading jQuery in noConflict mode after Prototype is a common mistake that can cause conflicts as jQuery will populate the `$` before clearing it out again so it can conflict in that short while during the loadup.

---

If you still want to trigger a click with prototype:

```
$(myelement).simulate('click');
```

This should do about the same as `.click();` does for jQuery

Comment: I didn't include jquery before prototype because I wanted it to be used only at one part of the application, but if having it loaded first for the entire application is the only solution I'll try it. Also, it's still nice if someone can translate that jquery code to prototype. I think, the bust solution would be not having more than one js library. Thanx!

Comment: I'v tried that too, I needed to include event.simulate.js, but I dunno why the simulate didn't work, and I couldn't even make the selector work...

Comment: Is the element available on the page when selecting? Maybe you will need to wait some time. Try using a `window.setTimeout(function() { yourselector },2000);` or something like that to see if the element enters the DOM after you selected. In that case the selector should work with that 2 second delay. If it's working like that you might want to add the event simulation to the callback (if available) for the loading routine of the selected content.

Comment: The problem is not the execution time, I can run the code after the script starts, or anytime later using Firebug or Chrome developer tools. I did include jquery, and it did work, but crashed other parts of the application. I'm tying to include jquery before every other library, but in Magento its not easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not understanding your question wrong, using $$ in prototype js should solve this. Prototype also support pseudoclasses like not, nth, first. You can take a look [here](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up with a 100% prototype solution. The simulate method is a plugin found in the internet. My biggest problem was that prototype doesn't like chaining as much as jQuery.

```
Event.simulate = function(element, eventName) {

      var options = Object.extend({
        pointerX: 0,
        pointerY: 0,
        button: 0,
        ctrlKey: false,
        altKey: false,
        shiftKey: false,
        metaKey: false,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      }, arguments[2] || { } );

      var eventMatchers = {
        'HTMLEvents': /load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll/,
        'MouseEvents': /click|mousedown|mouseup|mouseover|mousemove|mouseout/
      };

      var oEvent, eventType = null;

      for (var name in eventMatchers) {
        if (eventMatchers[name].test(eventName)) eventType = name;
      }

      if (!eventType) throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported');

      if (document.createEvent) {
        oEvent = document.createEvent(eventType);
        if (eventType == 'HTMLEvents') {
          oEvent.initEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable);
        }
        else {
          oEvent.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, document.defaultView, 
            options.button, options.pointerX, options.pointerY, options.pointerX, options.pointerY,
            options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button, $(element));
        }
        $(element).dispatchEvent(oEvent);
      }
      else {
        options.clientX = options.pointerX;
        options.clientY = options.pointerY;
        oEvent = Object.extend(document.createEventObject(), options);
        $(element).fireEvent('on' + eventName, oEvent);
      }
}

function selecionaOnload( atributo ){
    var elem = $$("div.atributoProduto."+atributo+" img.swatch:not(.disabledSwatch)").first();
    Event.simulate( elem, 'click');

    if(atributo == 'Cor'){
        $$("div.atributoProduto.Tamanho div.ico-esgotado").each(function(elem){
            elem.remove();
        });
        marcaIndisponivel('Tamanho');
    }
}

function marcaIndisponivel( atributo ){
    $$("div.atributoProduto."+atributo+" img.swatch.disabledSwatch").each(function(elem){
        elem.insert( {before:"<div class='ico-esgotado'></div>"} );
    });
}

Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  

    //marcaIndisponivel('Cor');
    selecionaOnload('Cor');
    marcaIndisponivel('Tamanho');
    //selecionaOnload('Tamanho');

});
```